# How to create folder in box using App Users?

Tags: box-api, box, boxapiv2

I am trying to create the folders in box by using the App Users. I already created the App User by following the below link given at box documentation:

https://box-content.readme.io/docs/app-users

But when I try to create the folder by following the below link:

https://box-content.readme.io/reference#create-a-new-folder

it shows that the folder is created by the enterprise admin user. So what should I pass when calling the create folder API which show me the folder is created by the particular App User?

Answer (score 1):

After you create the App User with the Enterprise access token, you need to generate an [App User access token](https://box-content.readme.io/docs/box-platform).

The App User access token will let you create a folder in that App User's account using the Create a Folder API endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the app user's `user_id` when generating the token to create the folder?

FYI: https://jwt.io/ can be very helpful for manually generating JWT tokens.